# How to create dialer style filter box in android custom title bar?

Tags: android

Hello Guys can you help me for creating a TextView in title  bar so that if we type 
'a' in that TextView than all entries in the ListView starting with 'a' only will get displayed.

The TextView will be something of type filterBox in Contact list.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can user Android Quick Search Box , referenced here
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/qsb.html